# Cufon fonts in Chrome very grainy

Tags: google-chrome

When using Chrome on Ubuntu, anything that uses Cufon is causing the fonts to become very grainy.  I have the same version of Chrome on Windows and I do not have this problem, it is only on Ubuntu.  I have attached an image below to show an example of what I mean.  This happens on any webpage that I go to using Cufon.  I can open the same page in Firefox and it looks fine.  I'm at a loss on this one.

[image: Grainy Cufon Image]

**UPDATE**

I have installed Ubuntu in a VM, installed the same version of Chrome, and all is well.  So this appears to only be happening on my computer, not on Ubuntu/Chrome as a whole.

Possible helful information:

- Ubuntu version: 10.10
- Chrome version: 11.0.696.34 beta

  - All extensions have been disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disable 3D acceleration in about:flags : same issue in Windows and Ubuntu 10.10 fixed with it.

Comment: That worked perfectly :) I forgot that I had messed around with those settings a while back. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For me I already had GPU Accelerated Compositing (which mentions 3D in it), so it wasn't that. But I did enable GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D at one point, and re-disabling that is the one that fixed it (which specifically mentions "canvas" and Cufon uses the canvas tag a lot).